# app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute(); выдает необработанное пользователем исключение

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

Делал по видео уроку сайт, делал все в точности как у него (видео 2019 года), но у меня ошибка.

Когда удаляю строчку с app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute(); то ничего не работает.

Контроллер, интерфейсы, модели, моки и представление есть.

Ошибка:

System.InvalidOperationException: "Endpoint Routing does not support 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc(...)'. To use 'IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc' set 'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside 'ConfigureServices(...)."

Comment: тут хороший тутор https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: а какая у вас версия asp.net core? и возможно стоит добавить starup.cs

Comment: startup.cs стоит, там я и добавлял app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();